# How to use react-navigation's SafeAreaView and avoid the space on the iPhone X?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

React Native introduced a while back the **SafeAreaView** component and it's now available as part of the react-navigation package which works awesome and solves the issue on iPhone X leaving space for the Home Indicator (bottom bar).

The one thing I can't figure out yet is how to change its style so it will "match" the rest of the page layout, no matter what I do it stays white and also add a bit of shadow for the element that is next to it from the top.

**Here are some screenshots:**

[image: SafeAreaView adds a white background]

[image: SafeAreaView adds a white background and some shadowing]

**Here's the code I use:**

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{'top': 'never'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Navigator/>
            <NotificationsContainer/>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
</Provider>
```

How can I modify this behavior and UI?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `backgroundColor` to it to change it according to the background color of the screen

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: //Your Primary Color}} forceInset={{'top': 'never'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Navigator/>
            <NotificationsContainer/>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

The shadow appears due to the card of the StackNavigator that you might have used. In order to remove it try removing the `elevation`, `shadowProps` for android and ios respectively as

```
const StackDemo = StackNavigator({
 // ...routes 
, {
  // ...props
  cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' },
});
```

Comment: This was a great tip, and it did indeed fill the iphone X notch. However, I still seem to get this border on the bottom of the notch area and can't seem to resolve it through the react native stylesheet styles. Any advice? Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/JUYjnYJ and App.js source: https://gist.github.com/tetreault/e44f12c462eda5956bf8943d2bd16ede . Edit: I wanted to point out I'm using View instead of SafeAreaView but the result is still the same either way.